# data structure for tables

Tags: data-structures, relational

If I have a table with each row representing a record, and there are several columns. I want to do fast queries and sorting on any of the columns. What data structures can I use?

I want to be space efficient. Otherwise, I could cache sorted results on each column for the queries and sorting. But how to consume less space, other than the table itself?

Comment: I suspect that this is going to need a lot more context? Is this in SQL? A procedural extension? Which RDBMS? Java? PHP? Python? C#? ...?

Comment: @Ben: Let's say just in any programming language e.g. Java.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your data, you may be looking for an implementation of [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). That is, an [unordered set of tuples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28database%29).

Commonly implementations are in some form of [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: Right, I understand B-tree can be used to save disk accesses. But don't you still have to make `m` auxiliary indices arrays if there are `m` columns for which one is to do sorting and queries?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a database programming question. You'll need indices, one per column (the rest of this answer will pretend that we're talking about a single index; just imagine doing all of this several times if you need to). Common solutions include hash tables and search trees (e.g. B-trees), but of course a simple solution that just contains all of the column entries is not particularly space-efficient.

The answer to that is making a *sparse* index: group your records in blocks and store only the record with the lowest search key from each block in your index. Unless you've got a pathological situation (very low values are added all the time), this will give you decent performance at low space requirements.

To deal with pathological situations, you could look at different ways to group records into blocks, e.g. by keeping a whole bunch of not-indexed-as-of-yet records and only committing a bunch of them into a group (and indexing that) whenever you can find a subset that isn't all over the place in terms of search keys.

(These are just ideas. I'm more of a user of databases than a programmer of them. Try some research to see what has been done in practice by people who know more than I do.)